# check if sqlite3 python data exists

Tags: python, database, sqlite

This is my code :

```
import sqlite3

def delete_product(data):
    with sqlite3.connect("main.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "delete from Products where Name=?"
        if cursor.rowcount <= 0:
            print("The product {0} does not exist" .format(name))
        if cursor.rowcount > 0:
            cursor.execute(sql,data)
            db.commit()
            print("The product {0} has been delted successfully" .format(name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name=input("Enter the name of the product you want to delete: >>")
    data=(name,)
    delete_product(data)
```

I want to check if the name actually exists in the database or not if it exists then delete it. if it doen't exist then print out an error. can anyone help me spot where the problem is

Comment: You should post full error message. It will help identify the problem.

Comment: You should probably specify what output do you get and why it is unexpected.

Comment: @beeftendon there is no error message it's just the checking if exists bit doesn't work

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych there is no output it just tells me the product doesnt exist even though it does

Comment: There is no need for any of this. Just execute "delete from Products where Name=?". If it exists, it's deleted. If it doesn't, nothing is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding cursors, the Python [`sqlite3` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects) states:

> As required by the Python DB API Spec, the rowcount attribute “is -1 in case no executeXX() has been performed on the cursor...

You define the cursor variable without performing any execute command. Thus, `cursor.rowcount` will be -1, and `cursor.rowcount <= 0` will always be true.

Maybe you intended to place the line

```
cursor.execute(sql,data)
```

before the first `cursor.rowcount` check?